# Single window media player with playlist

Tags: software-recommendation, music, media

Totem used to have single window mode with playlist. This mode of operation has been removed in new versions so I'm looking for a simple media player with similar features.

[image: Old version of totem]

Are there any media players with these features? I don't need any media library indexing or such, just a simple media player with playlist in single window.

Answer (score 1):

**Gnome-mplayer**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-mplayer
```

Just press F9 when you want to show playlist:

[image]

Comment: Ubuntus global media keys don't work with Gnome-mplayer